# Modifying plot across chunks

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I am trying to modify and re-display a plot in later code chunks. I thought the `global.device` option of `knitr` achieves that. Yet I am wondering why the latest plot is re-displayed when I execute some code on an intermittent slide.

My header is as follows:

````
---
output:
  beamer_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=F, cache=F}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(fig.width=4.5,
               fig.height=3,
               fig.align="center",
               echo=FALSE,
               cache=FALSE,
               eval=TRUE,
               message=FALSE)
knitr::opts_knit$set(global.device = TRUE)
````

Then I want to have three slides: The first displays a scatter, the second executes some code but does not display the plot, and the third modifies the plot and displays it again.

````
# Slide 1

Display a scatter plot.

```{r scatter}
data(mtcars)
mpg <- mtcars$mpg
wt <- mtcars$wt
plot(mpg, wt)
```    

# Slide 2

Some R code is evaluated. But print only text.

```{r reg_estimates}
model <- lm(wt ~ mpg)
``` 

# Slide 3

Plot a modified graph and close it.

```{r abline}
abline(model, lwd = 2, col="red")
out <- dev.off()
```
````

What puzzles me is that the plot of slide 1 is again displayed on slide 2. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`global.device` is going to do that for each intervening chunk. An alternative is to use `recordPlot` and `replayPlot` (both for base graphics):

````
---
output:
  beamer_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=F, cache=F}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(fig.width=4.5,
               fig.height=3,
               fig.align="center",
               echo=FALSE,
               cache=FALSE,
               eval=TRUE,
               message=FALSE)
# knitr::opts_knit$set(global.device = TRUE)
```

# Slide 1

Display a scatter plot.

```{r scatter}
data(mtcars)
mpg <- mtcars$mpg
wt <- mtcars$wt
plot(mpg, wt)
plt <- recordPlot()
```    

# Slide 2

Some R code is evaluated. But print only text.

```{r reg_estimates}
model <- lm(wt ~ mpg)
``` 

# Slide 3

Plot a modified graph and close it.

```{r abline}
replayPlot(plt)
abline(model, lwd = 2, col="red")
# out <- dev.off()
```
````

[image: three-page beamer slides, slide 2 has no plot]

Comment: This works fine. Thanks, @r2evans. Conceptually, what is the difference between, say, `plt <- recordPlot()` and simply `plt <- plot(mpg, wt)`. According to `ls.str()`, the latter seems to create an object in the workspace, but not the former.

Comment: When you do `plt <- plot(mpg, disp)`, do you have a return value? `plot.default` returns `NULL`, it operates solely in side-effect, returning nothing substantial. Other base-graphics plotting functions might return something, but never a "full plot", occasionally something that can be used to recreate the plot mathematically. This is in contrast to `ggplot2` and some other plotting methods that *return* something.

Comment: Side note, though, is that `recordPlot` works equally well on base graphics and `grid`-based graphics (e.g., `lattice` and `ggplot2`).